# Can the mutual information of a "cell" be negative?

Tags: mutual-information, information-theory, probability

Please forgive me if this is not the right Stack Exchange (and for inventing terms).

For discrete random variables X and Y, the mutual information of X and Y can be defined as follows:
$I(X;Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} \sum_{x \in X} 
                 p(x,y) \log{ \left( \frac{p(x,y)}{p_1(x)\,p_2(y)}
                              \right) }, \,\!$

I will define the mutual information of a "cell" $x_0$ to be:
$CI(x_0,Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} p(x_0,y) \log{ \left( \frac{p(x_0,y)}{p_1(x_0)\,p_2(y)}
                              \right) }, \,\!$

I'm not sure if this quantity goes by another name.  Essentially I'm restricting focus to a single state of variable X (and then the full MI can be calculated by summing all the cell MIs).

My question: is it guaranteed that $CI(x_0,Y) \ge 0$?  We know $I(X;Y)\ge0$ and we know that the pointwise mutual information can be negative.  I feel like CI should be nonnegative and that I might be missing some obvious proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3939/can-the-mutual-information-of-a-cell-be-negative/3943#3943).  CI cannot be negative.

The gist is that $CI=p(x_0) KL(p (y|x_0), p(y))$, and the Kullback-Leibler divergence is non-negative.

Comment: This is not an answer but a link to an answer on another SE website. Per the [help center guidelines](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) a good answer will both *answer the question* and *provide context for links* including relevant quotes and sources. The aim of CV is not to provide links to answers but solid answers *here*.

Comment: @becko Would be better if someone rolled into the answer why the KL divergence can't be negative.

Answer (score 1):

In,

$I(x,y)= \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x,y) \log_2 (\frac{p(x , y)}{p(x)p(y)})$

$CI(x,y)= \sum_{y \in Y} p(x,y) \log_2 (\frac{p(x , y)}{p(x)p(y)})$ for $x \in X$

we have,

$p(\cdot) \in [0,1]$

$\rightarrow\frac{p(\cdot)}{p(\cdot)p(\cdot)} \in [0...\infty ]$

$\rightarrow log_2\frac{p(\cdot)}{p(\cdot)p(\cdot)} \in (0...\infty ]$

$\rightarrow p(\cdot) log_2\frac{p(\cdot)}{p(\cdot)p(\cdot)} \in [0...\infty ]$

the codomain of $I$ and $CI$ is defined only on positive real values.

Comment: Your conclusion is right, but I think you've missed a step. Just because $X$ is non-negative doesn't mean $log_2(X)$ is positive. Trivially: $log_2(0.5) = -1$. You need a stronger constraint on what the product/quotient of the probabilities can be....